# Entity Framework .Include throwing NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a very basic EF setup that is throwing an odd error when trying to populate a navigation property by using .Include.  Here are the entity Models:

```
public class LineGroup
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }  
    public ICollection<LineGroupMember> LineGroupMembers { get; set; }
}

public class LineGroupMember
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Extension { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Permissions { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoggedIn { get; set; }

    public int LineGroupID { get; set; }

    internal LineGroup LineGroup { get; set; }
}
```

I am using these through an injected DB context, and can query each just fine without using navigation properties.  I can also query the LineGroups and include the LineGroupMembers property just fine, like so:

```
var LineGroups = _context.LineGroups.Include(l => l.LineGroupMembers).ToList();
```

This load all of the line groups into a list that has a correctly working "LineGroupMembers" collection for each Line Group. However, if I try

```
var lineGroupMembers = _context.LineGroupMembers.Include(m => m.LineGroup).ToList();
```

I get "NullReferenceException" with no helpful details.  Any ideas why the navigation property will work one way and not the other?  There are no null values in either database table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your navigation property `public`

```
public LineGroup LineGroup { get; set; }
```

If it is `internal` it won't be picked up by default by EF. You could also add explicit fluent mapping to force EF to recognize it as well.

Comment: Works, though original use for the internal was to prevent self reference error from json serialization.  For some reason the normal  "SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore" did not resolve this case.  However, adding [jsonignore] to the LineGroup property after making it public will work for my need.  Thanks!